# ComboBox doesn't take characters but takes numeric values

Tags: excel, vba

If I select a value from the dropdown menu and I try to run my code, it doesn't work. If instead, I manually input numeric values into "Fabricant" combobox, the code works. Why is that?

[image]

Code:

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If ComboBox1.Value = TRUE And TextBox1.Value = TRUE Then
        
        Sheets("Sheet1").Unprotect Password:="abc"
        Sheet1.Activate
        
        reponse = MsgBox("Êtes-vous sûr de vouloir générer une DMS pour appareil ?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Enregistrement CRN")
        
        If reponse = vbYes Then
            
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B4").Select
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
            
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B4:F4").Select
            Selection.Borders.Weight = xlThin
            
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B4").Select
            ActiveCell.Value = "=b5+1"
            
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A4").Select
            Selection.Borders.Weight = xlThin
            ActiveCell.Value = "FA-"
            
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C4").Select
            Selection.Borders.Weight = xlThin
            ActiveCell.Value = ".6"
            
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("d4").Select
            Selection.Borders.Weight = xlThin
            ActiveCell.Value = TextBox1.Value
            
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E4").Select
            Selection.Borders.Weight = xlThin
            ActiveCell.Value = ComboBox1.Value
            
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F4").Select
            Selection.Borders.Weight = xlThin
            ActiveCell.Value = Environ("username")
            
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G4").Select
            Selection.Borders.Weight = xlThin
            ActiveCell.Value = Now
            
            cell_value = Sheet1.Cells(4, "A").Value & Format$(Sheet1.Cells(4, "B").Value, "0000#") & Format$(Sheet1.Cells(4, "C").Value, ".0")
            
        Else
            MsgBox ("Erreur")
            Sheets("Sheet1").Protect Password:="abc"
            
            Exit Sub
            
        End If
        MsgBox Replace("Le nouveau DMS enregistré est le : " & cell_value, ",", ".")
        
        CommandButton1_Click
        Unload Me
        'UserForm1.Show
        Sheets("Sheet1").Protect Password:="abc"
       
        
    End If
End Sub
```

This is how I populate my combobox:

[image]

The values are on Sheet4 A1:A10

Comment: How do you populate your combobox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you're trying to check with this:

```
If ComboBox1.Value = TRUE And TextBox1.Value = TRUE
```

If what you're trying to achieve is to check whether the `ComboBox` and the `TextBox` have been filled in by the user, as opposed to having been left blank, then that's not the way to do it.

This condition `ComboBox1.Value = TRUE` returns the boolean value `TRUE` if the `ComboBox` holds either a non zero numeric value or the string "true" (non case sensitive). It returns the boolean value `FALSE`in all other cases.

So, this if-condition:

```
If ComboBox1.Value = TRUE And TextBox1.Value = TRUE
```

will be resolved as `TRUE` only if both boxes hold a non zero numeric value or the string "true", in any combination.

This means that when you assign a string to your `combobox` that is different from "True" (non case sensitive), the if-condition will always be false.

If you want to check whether your boxes are blank you should do this instead:

```
If ComboBox1.Value <> "" And TextBox1.Value <> "" then
```